# Quadratic Diophanthine Equation

Tags: number-theory

I got this question from RMO-2014

> Find all $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n^2-440$ is a perfect square.

My attempt:

Let $n^2-440=(n-k)^2$

Then $k^2-2nk+440=0$

This gives $k=\frac{2n\pm2\sqrt{n^2-440}}{2}$, which gives $n=k$, which gives $n\not\in\mathbb N$ or $k=k$, which is useless.

$21$ is an answer, by trial and error, but I can't go any further.

Please help.

Comment: Difference of two squares!

Comment: Suppose that $n^2-440$ is a perfect square.  Then $n^2-440=m^2$ for some $m$ and by rearranging we get $n^2-m^2=440$ i.e. $(n+m)(n-m)=440=2^3\cdot5\cdot11$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $441$ is a square, but $440$ isn't.

Comment: @JMoravitz. Oh. I see. Thanks.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo:  you should write up the answer based on JMoravitz' hint.  The FAQ encourages that.  You will see if you understand it properly and we will have an answer for the question.

Comment: @RossMillikan Very well. I shall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n^2-440=m^2$.

Then $(n+m)(n-m)=440$

$440=2^3\cdot5\cdot11$.

Now, $440$ can be represented as

$\begin{align}1&\times440\\2&\times220\\4&\times110\\5&\times88\\8&\times55\\10&\times44\\11&\times40\\20&\times22 \end{align}$

So we have if $n+m=a,n-m=b$, we have $n=\frac{a+b}2$. This is integral only when, in this case, $a,b$ are both even.

So we get $n=21,27,57,111$.